# Simpler/better way to see if colours match in 2D array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a btn 2D array 6,7 named grid and I want to scan to see if there are four yellows or reds in a row horizontally, vertically and diagonally. At the moment I'm using if statements and placing some in for loops if possible such as;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   if (grid[i, 0].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 1].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 2].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 3].BackColor == Color.Red
       || grid[i, 1].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 2].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 3].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 4].BackColor == Color.Red
       || grid[i, 2].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 3].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 4].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 5].BackColor == Color.Red
       || grid[i, 3].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 4].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 5].BackColor == Color.Red && grid[i, 6].BackColor == Color.Red)
   {
       txtBoxWinner.Text = "RED is the WINNER";
   }
}
```

Can someone help me look for a shorter alternative? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using a 2d array, create a proper Collection of a proper Data Model than can be traversed with LINQ. And instead of having your application logic based on the state of UI elements' properties, create a proper Collection of a proper Data model that can be traversed with LINQ.

Comment: That sounds far too advanced for where I am at the moment. I'm looking to stick with the array. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 1):

This just feels cleaner to me

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     int correctCount = 0;
     for (int j = i; j < i + 3 && j < 7; j++)
     {
          if (grid[i, j].BackColor == Color.Red)
                correctCount++;
     }
     if (correctCount >= 3)
         txtBoxWinner.Text = "RED is the WINNER"; 
}
```

Sorry, before I didn't realize you had or statements in there also...This should do it though.

Comment: @user3392999 Check edits, I fixed it, sorry before I hadn't realized you had or statements in there

Comment: It's telling me "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: @user3392999 Then change `j < 7` to `j < 6` I may have used the wrong sized array in my testing